# Combining multiple columns into a unique list without blanks that can be filtered by users

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying some methods that have gotten the list to display correctly, however when adding a filter button, it filters the formula far down the sheet. I understand that the problem is that the formula is only included in the top cell and cannot be dragged down.

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX(VSTACK(SKUs!B$3:B$1000,SKUs!E$3:E$1000,SKUs!H$3:H$1000,SKUs!K$3:K$1000,SKUs!N$3:N$1000,SKUs!Q$3:Q$1000,SKUs!T$3:T$1000),, MATCH(TRUE, VSTACK(SKUs!B$3:B$1000,SKUs!E$3:E$1000,SKUs!H$3:H$1000,SKUs!K$3:K$1000,SKUs!N$3:N$1000,SKUs!Q$3:Q$1000,SKUs!T$3:T$1000)<>"", 0)))
```

The code works when first displayed, but when a filter is applied the whole list gets sent down hundreds of rows as the text it displays in the first cells begins with a 'V'. I have assumed that the way to fix it is to create a formula that can be dragged down, but I'm no genius.

I know its a bit janky and I'm not the most gifted formula writer but this has really stumped me and I don't know the solution. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have tagged both `excel` AND `google-sheets`. Please choose one or the other and delete the extra tag.

Comment: `Match(true,(condition),0)` will returns 1 value only.

Answer (score 0):

`=UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(SKUs!A3:T1000,SEQUENCE(7,,2,3)),1))`

`TOCOL` with argument `1` (skip blanks) will stack all non blank values from given range.

Where you want to get the results from 7 different columns, starting at column 2 (B:B) and offset 3 columns each time. You could use SEQUENCE inside CHOOSECOLS.

[image]

Comment: When I enter it, it returns a #VALUE with the error "Function CHOOSECOLS parameter 2 expects number values, but got error."

Also I don't know if this will help the filtering issue given that it works similarly to the previously used code

Comment: Added a screenshot for the result

Comment: This method still runs into the same issue of not being able to filter.

Comment: Maybe because you tagged both Excel and Google sheets, they're not the same. This is Excel

Comment: `=unique(tocol(choosecols(B3:T1000;sequence(7;1;1;3)); 1))` works in sheets as well. You just need to define all parameters of sequence. (May need to change delimiter to comma)